# Debug web service running on local machine?

Tags: web-services, iis-7, powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder Classic 12.1 to deploy a .NET Web Services target to IIS 7 running on my local machine. I'd like to be able to debug it. The documentation from Sybase says I should be able to. But when I run the debugger it says "Attaching to ASP.NET worker" and "Time left: 20 seconds". It counts down to 0 and then I see "Failed attaching to ASP.NET worker process."

I'm running PowerBuilder as an administrator, so I don't think that's the problem.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Open your your **project object** that you are using to deploy with. If you have multiple project objects, then right click on your target in the tree-view painter and click preferences to open a dialog that let's you choose which target object will be used for deployment.  Choose the one that is set **with DEBUG symbol** on and set to **debug build**.

I have had good luck debugging PB Web Services both IIS hosted and self-hosted.

I also found this in the PowerBuilder help file for you:

**Using the DEBUG symbol**

If you used the DEBUG conditional compilation symbol in code for the nonvisual objects you deploy as a Web service and you want this code to run, you must make sure that the enable DEBUG symbol check box is selected before you deploy the project. If you plan to debug the assembly or Web service, you should make sure the project is deployed as a debug build.

> ** added additional details here on 1-26-13
>
> This blog article will help you get WCF debugging to work in PowerBuilder.NET.
>
> [Testing & Debugging PowerBuilder.NET WCF Web Services](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/debug-powerbuilder-wcf-web-services-testing)

Comment: I'm only using one project object for deployment. It has Build type set to Debug and the Enable DEBUG symbol is checked.

Comment: Ok, I recommend using the WCF Test Client window for testing your WCF service, it is included with Visual Studio (wcftestclient.exe) and after opening the test client and adding your web service you can go into PB.NET and use menu item Debug --> Debug <your web service name> and then you will be prompted with an Attach Security Warning dialog that attaches w3wp.exe with your IIS App Pool.  Click on Attach and then use the test client to test your methods, your breakpoints will work-- PB will flash when breakpoint hit. fyi - you will probably time-out on your WCF service when debugging